# FDB file extension may what database?

Tags: database, sybase, firebird, fdb

I got a fdb file, I thought it's a firebird database file, but cant't open using firebird, and I try sybase again, not work.
this file used for a B/S software (java) client cache, maybe pretty old database, and this is not a compressed file,I can see may strings in file, the file head start with:

10 00 00 00 00 40 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00

any suggestion?

this is the file,please have a look
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qorhd21f328pfj2/PRINT_TEMPLATE_CACHE.fdb?dl=0

Comment: "but cant't open using firebird" What exactly is happening?

Comment: Which Firebird version did you try and what error did you get? You should really provide more information; for example what is "a B/S software", have you tried asking the vendor?

Comment: Also are those groups of numbers hexadecimal? If the first byte is actually 0x10, then it is not a Firebird database, because the database header page is 0x01, and there only exist page types 0x01 - 0x0a.

Comment: Seems that bunch of databases beside Firebird use fdb extension: http://filext.com/file-extension/FDB

Comment: yes, the first byte is 0x10, I tried firebird and sybase ,got "not a valid database" error,this one has no database name string in file head

Comment: and this software pretty big and has may years history, looks like 20year,I asked someone (non-core developer) worked in that compay,the answer is don't know,

Comment: do you have access sources of that app ? I guess you would have to look for filenames/extensions to find which classes do deal with that file, then which classes use those classes, then which classes use the classes that use those classes, and go on bottom-up until there would be some hint if that file is some standard format. It also might happen to be you own in-house developed custom format as well

Comment: real good idea, hope the client not encrypted, thank you.